# How to add library in arquillian service deployment?

Tags: java, junit, jboss, jboss-arquillian, jmockit

i'm currently using Arquillian for jboss(remote) and i'm trying to make Jmockit work. I deployed an ear which works fine, but i'm getting this error for arquillian-service:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: mockit/internal/state/TestRun

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: mockit.internal.state.TestRun from 
[Module "deployment.arquillian-service:main" from Service Module Loader]
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190)
```

I'm using jMockit 1.7 and have it in EAR deployment.

How can i add library in this deployment (arquillian-service)

PS: This deployment is managed by arquillian, i have nothing to do with it.

Comment: I have little experience with Arquillian, so I don't know the answer; but what kind of tests are these? are they functional tests using Selenium WebDriver or HTMLUnit, or just integration tests for Java code that run in-container? In either case, is there really a need for mocking in such tests?

Comment: Add the code for the test.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem of third-party libs as follows - 
the list of dependencies:

```
protected static final String[] DEPENDENCIES = {
        ...,
        "xbean:xbean:2.4.0",
        ...
};
```

Method which packs all them into separate jar:

```
protected JavaArchive thirdPartyLibs() {
    JavaArchive lib = ShrinkWrap.create(JavaArchive.class, "libs.jar");
    for (String dependency : DEPENDENCIES) {
        lib.merge(Maven.resolver().resolve(dependency).withoutTransitivity().asSingle(JavaArchive.class));
    }
    return lib;
}
```

Eventually I merge it when packing core jar:

```
protected JavaArchive createJar() {
    return ShrinkWrap.create(JavaArchive.class, "test.jar")
            .addAsManifestResource("META-INF/test-persistence.xml", ArchivePaths.create("persistence.xml"))
            .addAsManifestResource("META-INF/test-beans.xml", ArchivePaths.create("beans.xml"))
            .....
            .merge(thirdPartyLibs());
}
```

Also to use this next dependencies must be pointed out:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver</groupId>
        <artifactId>shrinkwrap-resolver-bom</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver</groupId>
        <artifactId>shrinkwrap-resolver-impl-maven</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver</groupId>
        <artifactId>shrinkwrap-resolver-impl-maven-archive</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: While this mecanism is working in terms of adding the libraries to the jar file created by ShrinkWrap, in my case I am getting issues with classes using java annotations, i.e., java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError. It seems that java is not able to find the required classes, even though the dependencies are merged correctly in the generated jar. Is there something missing?

Comment: Actually I also observe some exceptions mostly related to JavaDocs or something like that. They seem to be not critical since do not affect tests, just make logs less pretty. I spent some time trying to fix them but no success.

Comment: In my case, the java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError messages seems to be critical since Arquillian is not able to deploy the created war file.