# add packages in deployment jar using shrinkWrap in arquillian test

Tags: java, jboss, ejb, jboss-arquillian

I am using arquillian for unit test. I am creating deployment jar using shrinkWrap. But for that I need to add all the packages which are used in my project, which are a lot in number.

following is my test file

```
@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class GreeterTest {



    @Deployment
    public static JavaArchive createDeployment() throws NamingException {

        return ShrinkWrap.create(JavaArchive.class, "test.jar")
                .addPackage(ABC.class.getPackage())
                .addPackage(EFG.class.getPackage())
                .addPackage(HIJ.class.getPackage())
                .addPackage(KLM.class.getPackage())
                .addPackage(NOP.class.getPackage())
                .addPackage(QRS.class.getPackage())
                .addPackage(TUV.class.getPackage())
                .addPackage(XYZ.class.getPackage())

                .addAsResource("test-persistence.xml", "META-INF/persistence.xml")
                .addAsManifestResource(EmptyAsset.INSTANCE, "beans.xml");

      }

    @Inject
    ABC abc;

    @Inject
    EFG efg;

    @Inject
    HIJ hij;

    @Inject
    KLM klm;

    @Inject
    NOP nop;

    @Test
    public void shouldBeAbleToInjectEJBAndInvoke() throws Exception {

        abc.getDetail();

    }
}
```

You can see .addPackage(). there are hundreds of packages in my project. Obvious code size will be increasing enormously

Is there any other way for this? Or I must be making some big mistake

Comment: BTW. Your resource definition is wrong. Should be: `.addAsManifestResource("META-INF/test-persistence.xml", "persistence.xml");`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I'd recommend you to use string representation of package path: "com.root.core" etc. And there are methods:

```
addPackage(String pack)

addPackages(boolean recursive, String... packages)
```

The latest is more appropriate for you I guess as it provides you a possibility to add packages recursively and thus you avoid repeatedly including every package. For instance:

```
.addPackages(true, "com.root")
```

Comment: It worked. Thanx. But now its giving me same error for library m using, like org.codehaus, com.google

Comment: Generaly it should resolve dependencies. You can try to add that problem dependencies manually. I already described the approach here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30932182/how-to-add-library-in-arquillian-service-deployment/31044392#31044392

Answer (score 0):

You can use the existing `EAR/WAR/JAR` of your app because creating `EAR` with `ShrinkWrap` would be annoying in some complex cases (many dependencies etc).
The `@Deployment` method should embed the test WAR into the EAR and add a module element into existing `application.xml` before returning the archive to Arquillian runtime.

A `@Deployment` method example:

```
...
@Deployment
public static Archive<?> createDeploymentPackage() throws IOException {
    final String testWarName = "test.war";

    final EnterpriseArchive ear = ShrinkWrap.createFromZipFile(
            EnterpriseArchive.class, new File("target/myApp.ear"));

    addTestWar(ear, myClassTest.class, testWarName);
...
```

[Arquillian EJB-JAR/EAR testing examples](http://www.nailedtothex.org/roller/kyle/entry/arquillian-ejb-jar-ear-testing)

[Arquillian EJB-JAR/EAR testing examples/Github](https://github.com/lbtc-xxx/arquillian-ear/blob/master/ear/src/test/java/org/example/EarFromZipFileIT.java)

---

[SO: How to add test classes to an imported ear file and run server side with arquillian?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14713129/how-to-add-test-classes-to-an-imported-ear-file-and-run-server-side-with-arquill)